# Definition of an integral over linear maps

Tags: measure-theory, representation-theory, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group with Haar measure $\mu$. Let $\varphi \colon G \to GL(V)$ be a continuous representation of $G$, where $V$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$. Let $C_c(G)$ be the vector space of compactly supported functions $G \to \mathbb C$. Then I've seen the definition
$$
\varphi(f) = \int_{g \in G} f(g) \varphi(g) d \mu(g)
$$
and I fail to understand what this means and how this integral is defined. I know how an integral over $\mathbb C$-valued functions is defined in measure theory, but now $\varphi(g)$ is a linear map, albeit one over a $\mathbb C$-vector space. Could anyone help me out? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral

Comment: If "continuous representation" means that the mapping $(g,v)\mapsto\varphi(g)(v)$ from $G\times V$ to $V$ is continuous, I imagine it could be possible for $\varphi$ not to be measurable in the sense of Bochner... So I guess it would be safer to go with [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral).

Comment: It means the map $G \to GL(V)$ is continuous for the topology on $GL(V)$ coming from the operator norm. Continuous functions are measurable, I'd hope

Comment: Yes, continuous functions are measurable in the sense of Bochner. But very often, representations aren't continuous for the operator norm topology (e.g. the [regular representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation) of $\mathbf R$ in $\mathrm L^2(\mathbf R)$) and I think the regular representations of $G$ in $\mathrm L^2(G)$ are measurable in the sense of Bochner for the operator norm topology if and only if $G$ is discrete.

Comment: Most of the time, the worst representations $\varphi:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ one gets to work with are at least such that for every $v,w\in V$, the scalar function $g\mapsto\langle\varphi(g)v,w\rangle$ is continuous, i.e. $\varphi$, as a mapping from $G$ to $L(V)$, is continuous when $L(V)$ is endowed with the weak topology associated to the topology of pointwise convergence. So most of the time, the safe thing to do is to consider representations as mappings from $G$ to $L(V)$ with $L(V)$ endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence, and use the Pettis integral.